# What is the conical mouthpart of a soldier termite and what does it do?

Tags: entomology

I'm trying to get a visual understanding of termite anatomy and I'm getting quite confused on the protruding mouthpart area (it looks like a beak) located between the pincers.

What does it do / what is it for? It does not look like a chewing mouthpart.

Further, is it related to the mouthparts of the worker / females termites?

Oddly enough, I found "Conehead" termites with what appears to be a far more profound version of this part (though it might not be) and again I see no purpose for it.

Is there a place on the internet where the breakdown of termites can be found? This would be very useful.

[image: What is between the pincers?]

*What is between the pincers?*

Answer (score -1):

This is actually the termite's labrum. Its quite big in termites. Does not have value in telling male from female.

Comment: Hi Jules~verne. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Answers that don't include explanations may be removed. Please update. Thanks! :)